Issue with session authentication not being preserved across calls from React frontend to Django backend
I have the following code:
LoginPage.js:
import React from  'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Grid, TextField } from '@mui/material'

import DisplayAppBar from './DisplayAppBar';

export default function LoginPage() {

    const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login/', {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }).then((response) => {
                // navigate('/home'); // Navigate to home page
                axios.get("http://localhost:8000/check-login-status/")
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    // return <Navigate to="/" />;
                })
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <DisplayAppBar />
            <Grid container direction="column" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" spacing={2} >
                <Grid item>
                    <TextField required label="Username" variant="outlined" id="usernameField" onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <TextField required label="Password" variant="outlined" id="passwordField" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleLogin}>Login</Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
};

urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from TeamData import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('club/', views.ClubListCreate.as_view()),
    path('club/<int:pk>/', views.ClubDetail.as_view()),
    path('swimmer/', views.SwimmerListCreate.as_view()),
    path('swimmer/<int:pk>/', views.SwimmerDetail.as_view()),
    path('user/', views.UserListCreate.as_view()),
    path('user/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('signup/', views.UserListCreate.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('check-login-status/', views.CheckLoginStatus.as_view(), name='check-login-status'),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)

views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout, login
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import generics
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from .models import Club, Swimmer, User
from .serializers import ClubSerializer, SwimmerSerializer, UserSerializer, LoginSerializer
    
class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class LogoutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
class CheckLoginStatus(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Response({'is_authenticated': True})
        else:
            return Response({'is_authenticated': False})

class UserListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=self.request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            user = User.objects.get(username=self.request.data['username'])
            user.set_password(self.request.data['password'])
            user.save()
            return Response({'user': serializer.data})
        return Response(serializer.errors)

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class ClubListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Club.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer

class ClubDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Club.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer

class SwimmerListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Swimmer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SwimmerSerializer
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    # def perform_create(self, serializer):
        
    #     user_data = self.request.data.pop('user', None)

    #     if user_data:
    #         user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=user_data)
    #         user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    #         user = user_serializer.save()
    #         serializer.save(user=user)
    #     else:
    #         serializer.save()

class SwimmerDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Swimmer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SwimmerSerializer

and serializers.py:
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from .models import (Club, Swimmer, Group, SwimmerGroup, Coach, GroupCoaches, Admin, 
                     GroupPractices, Competition, CompetitionCoachDelegations, 
                     CompetitionSwimmersAttending, EventRecord, Event, Entry)

class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        username = attrs.get('username')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if not user:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid credentials')
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Must include "username" and "password"')
        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'username', 'password']
    
class ClubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Club
        fields = '__all__'

class SwimmerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Swimmer
        fields = '__all__'

When I 'successfully' login (from LoginPage.js) (i.e., enter correct information and get response confirming that the information was correct), I am running into a problem where the following get to check-login-status still returns that the user is not authenticated. Can anyone see the issue which might be causing this?
I'm not sure how to proceed based on information online - I believe it may be related to session ID preservation but I'd appreciate any guidance.
